# Installing SolarisStudio fails

Tags: solaris

ALL,

Hopefully I can find a person who know Solaris. If not I'd appreciate a pointer where to ask...

I installed Solaris 11.1 on the VirtualBox VM. Then I tried to install SolarisStudio 12.5 on top. It failed. I asked on solaris ML and got a pointer that SolarisStudio requires 11.2+.

So I updated my OS installation and tried again. Below is what I got:

```
igor@solaris:~$ sudo pkg install --accept developerstudio-125Password:
Creating Plan (Running solver): |
 pkg install: No solution was found to satisfy constraints

 maintained incorporations:
  pkg://solaris/consolidation/SunVTS/SunVTS-incorporation@7.19.2-0.175.3.0.0.26.3
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/X/X-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.2.1489
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/admin/admin-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/cacao/cacao-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.24.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/cde/cde-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.16.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/cns/cns-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.24.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/dbtg/dbtg-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.29.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/ddt/ddt-incorporation@8.9.15.9.11
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.28.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/desktop/gnome-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/gfx/gfx-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/java-7/java-7-incorporation@1.7.0.85.33-0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/java-8/java-8-incorporation@1.8.0.60.27-0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/jdmk/jdmk-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.22.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/l10n/l10n-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.2
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/man/man-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.28.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/nspg/nspg-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/nvidia/nvidia-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.17.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/sfw/sfw-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/sic_team/sic_team-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.20.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/solaris_re/solaris_re-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/ssm/ssm-incorporation@2.3.3.0-0.175.3.0.0.29.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.9.0.2.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/ub_javavm-6/ub_javavm-6-incorporation@1.6.0.999.99-0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0
   pkg://solaris/consolidation/xvm/xvm-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
   pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.1

 Plan Creation: Package solver is unable to compute solution.
 Dependency analysis is unable to determine exact cause.
 Try specifying expected results to obtain more detailed error messages.
 Include specific version of packages you wish installed.
```

Does anybody have an idea of what might be an issue here? I can try and post any other information by request but you need to be more specific as I don't know my around OS. I'm more familiar with Linux.

Thank you for any pointers.

[EDIT]

```
igor@solaris:~$ uname -a
SunOS solaris 5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc
igor@solaris:~$ cat /etc/release
                             Oracle Solaris 11.3 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 06 October 2015
```

[/EDIT]

[EDIT1]

```
igor@solaris:~$ sudo pkg set-publisher -k ~/Downloads/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem -c ~/Downloads/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem -G "*" -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release solarisstudio
igor@solaris:~$ sudo pkg list -af 'pkg://solarisstudio/developer/solarisstudio-125/*'pkg list: no packages matching 'pkg://solarisstudio/developer/solarisstudio-125/*' known
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/release`?

Comment: @fpmurphy1, question updated with answer.

Comment: Did you follow all documented steps/tests? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/html/E60743/gozsz.html

Comment: @jlliagre, question updated. Is it possible I got wrong certificate?

Comment: How did you update your OS installation?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I ran "pkg image-update -v && pkg refresh --full" following this link: https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Updating+OpenSolaris+to+OpenIndiana.

Comment: Ouch! While they both come from a common source code, Solaris 11.3 are OpenIndiana have diverged quite a lot. The fork happened seven years ago… You should never "upgrade" Solaris 11.1 to OpenIndiana, they are different operating systems.

Comment: @jlliagre, so are you saying I currently have an OpenIndiana and not Solaris? And I can't install SolarisStudio currently? If yes - what should I do? I can nuke the OS and start over with Solaris 11.1, since its all VM, but "pkg image-update -v" will update me to the same OS/version... Or maybe it will be easier to grab Solaris 11.3 and install it?

Comment: You can go from 11.1 to 11.3 with pkg update --accept. See more here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54845/gmplg.html#IOSUPgmpmc

Comment: Your system is reporting it is Oracle Solaris 11.3 but you wrote you followed a documentation which explains how to update an older Operating System (OpenSolaris)  to OpenIndiana. There is then a discrepancy. I have no idea about what impact following that documentation might had on your system. Anything between nothing at all and a total mess is possible. I haven't installed Solaris Studio recently so I can't give up to date advice about possible pitfalls with the current OS and Studio versions.

Comment: @jlliagre, can you point me to the instruction on how to update {SOpen}Solaris 11.1 to 11.2+? Google gave me the link I provided. And I can probably nuke that OS and start over. Like I said it is a VM, so its easy. ;-)

Comment: There is no such thing as "OpenSolaris 11.1". I would suggest to download and directly install Solaris 11.3.

Comment: @jlliagre ok, I will download 11.3 and install it on VM.The current one will be nuked. Thx.

Comment: @jlliagre, I found this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/install-2245079.html, but am confused now. When I tried to install OpenSolaris 11.1 I booted up (in GNOME)and then click on the icon "Install OpenSolaris". Now it looks like I will have either a text installer or a network installer. Can I do a local installation by doing the same thing I did initially? Or maybe I should restart and follow instructions from BitsOfNix post?

Comment: Again, there is no such thing a **Open Solaris 11.1**. Please pay attention to what is displayed which should read **Oracle Solaris 11.3**. To install from the live media, follow the instructions available here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-112-s11-first-steps-524819.html ; there is definitely a graphic installer.

Comment: @jlliagre, yes OpenSolaris is dead with Sun. It just I am a retro-person.

Comment: @jlliagre I think the OS installation would be just fine once you tighten the bolts in its neck...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, you tried to update a version of Solaris 11 to OpenIndiana which wouldn't be supported.

You could booting to an old BE if you haven't already.
`beadm list`
Followed by a `beadm activate *<_an_older_beName_>*` with an `init 6`

And then start your upgrade again using the Oracle procs, if you haven't just tried to install a new VM with v11.3.

Comment: and the proper update procedure is in the BitsOfNix answer, right?